# Cannot Load my iniFile during testing and debugging with gopkg.in/ini.v1

Tags: go, ini

This is a my Go project.

```
.
├── cmd
│   └── main
│       └── main.go
├── config
│   └── config.go
│
├── config.ini
```

usually it is executable go run and go build.

but cannot execute during testing and debugging.(go test ./cmd/main and vscode debug)
with error below

```
config.ini: no such file or directory
```

I tried change path to ../../config.ini.
It worked fine, however could not execute go run and build.

how can I set path to executable with all environments?

config/config.go

```
package config

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/ini.v1"
)

type ConfigList struct {
    FgiAPIKey  string
    FgiAPIHost string
    Port       int
    JwtAccess  string
    JwtRefresh string
}

var Config ConfigList

func init() {
    cfg, err := ini.Load("config.ini")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to read file: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    Config = ConfigList{
        FgiAPIKey:  cfg.Section("fgi").Key("api_key").String(),
        FgiAPIHost: cfg.Section("fgi").Key("api_host").String(),
        Port:       cfg.Section("web").Key("port").MustInt(),
        JwtAccess:  cfg.Section("secret").Key("jwt_access").String(),
        JwtRefresh: cfg.Section("secret").Key("jwt_refresh").String(),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that different tools you use produce binary in (or run binary from) different place. Path to `config.ini` in your code is specified as relative to process' current working directory. If you want non-invasive solution you'd need to change your workflow (where you build and run the main binary, debugger or go test) or you can implement some fallback mechanism or environment variable that will override default path to config file.

In VSCode there should be `cwd` variable in `launch.json` configuration that allows you to set working directory. You should be able to set `cwd: "${workspaceFolder}"` and that should work as if you run commands from the root of repository.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference for variables reference.

Comment: Thank you your advices.
I solved it.

vscode is using debugging only.
`"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"`

testing and running are setting os.GetEnv.
` cfg, err := ini.Load(os.Getenv("SRC_ROOT") + "/config.ini")`